# How to extract params from JSON edpoint url in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, endpoint

I've been struggling with this task for few hours now. As I've never used JSON format before, I have no idea how to extract params from URL I receive to my endpoint API.

Let's say I have url like this:

```
/endpoint/name=anna&email=whatever@example.com
```

But request format is:

```
/endpoint.json?name=:name&email=:email
```

How do I extract those parameters? I've tried creating method like this:

```
def get_params
  response = request.body
  @user = JSON.parse(response)
end
```

But I'm not even sure how to test it properly.

Should I create a route for the POST I'm getting?

Answer (score 1):

If your URL is `/endpoint.json?name[]=anna&email[]=whatever@example.com` (i.e. just a normal index route for an `Endpoint` resource that responds to json), you can get the name array with `params[:name]` and the email array with `params[:email]`.

Comment: You mean I can extract it like this: 
`@name = JSON.parse(params[:name])` ? When I try this, I'm getting 757: unexpected token' error.

Comment: No need to parse JSON. `params[:name]` in your case will be an array of names (in this particular example, just an array of one name: "anna"). You can say something like `@names = params[:name]` or `@name = params[:name].first`. See this section for an explanation http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters

Comment: Ohh right, of course! I've updated my answer with the line `/endpoint.json?name=:name&email=:email` that confuses me. I did get the vaues from params as you and @vpsz said I would but I'm having some routing errors now. I was testing everything with URL format: `/?name=anna` instead of `/endpoint/name=anna`. No question mark, no folder path. Do you happen to know what routes should I have for that POST request?

Comment: @ZuzannaSt for POST requests, you should not be submitting query params in the URL.I assume what you want is to actually send JSON such as `{"name": "anna", "email": "whatever@example.com"}`. This data should be sent in the body of the HTTP request, and the `Content-Type `header of that request should read `application/json`. On this page, you can see a basic example of how to send a POST JSON request in jQuery http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ . Your server-side route should be just `POST /endpoint`. Using query params in the URL would be bad practice for a JSON API.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a normal route for your JSON endpoint. The query string parameters will be made available through the `params` hash as always.